# Jasper Reports con una tabla temporal

Tags: jasper-reports, tablas

Estoy realizando reportes en JasperReports Studio para una aplicación web. Los informes se conectan a la aplicación a través de un Sp y ejecutan en pdf el reporte que están en formato .jrxml.

Los reportes me han funcionado sin problemas hasta que me vi en la obligación de **usar una tabla temporal** para un reporte. **El problema es que a la hora de ejecutarlo no carga nada**. El reporte esta bien alimentado ya que en el ambiente de eclipse carga sin problemas y el sp cuando lo ejecuto por aparte con la información que me manda la aplicación también funciona bien y devuelve los valores correctos. Asumo que la falla se da porque por algun motivo la función no podía leer el procedimiento si este tena almacenado la creación de la tabla temporal, por lo cual cree un procedimiento a parte para crear la tabla temporal y lo ejecuto desde el procedimiento que crea el reporte.

También revise que a tabla temporal se borre si existe antes de que el procedimiento la vuelva a crear. Si alguien mas ha trabajado reportes de jasper por plsql, sabe cual es el problema o tienen alguna guía que me ayude a solucionarlo lo agradecería

Reporte en jasper:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respuesta en sql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
    DECLARE @WHERE VARCHAR(8000)


DECLARE @CY INT = (SELECT [FK_CY] FROM [tbl_Adm_Usuarios] WHERE [Id_US] = 1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Consolidado') IS NOT NULL BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.##Consolidado
    END

  EXEC dbo. sp_Crear_Tabla_Temp_Activos @CY


IF (@TIPOVISIBLE = '1') BEGIN
    SET @WHERE = (SELECT [dbo].[fn_ObtenerWhereRT](@US, @MOD, @SUB, 'A.[FK_CY] = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CY)))
END

IF (@TIPOVISIBLE = '2') BEGIN
    SET @WHERE = 'A.[FK_CY] = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CY)
END

IF (@TIPOVISIBLE = '3') BEGIN
    SET @WHERE = 'A.[FK_CY] = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @CY) + ' AND A.[Id_AC] = ' + @ID
END



    SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT 
    A.Id_AC 
    ,A.FK_CY 
    ,A.vrc_CodigoAC 
    ,A.vrc_SerialAC 
    ,A.vrc_DescripcionAC 
    ,A.vrc_ModeloAC 
    ,A.int_CodigoCC 
    ,A.vrc_DescripcionCC 
    ,A.vrc_CodigoUF 
    ,A.vrc_DescripcionUF 
    ,A.Tipo 
    ,A.int_AnoOT 
    ,A.Numero
    ,A.Descripcion
    ,A.dat_FechaCreacion 
    ,A.dat_FechaInicioTrabajos 
    ,A.dat_FechaFinTrabajos 
    ,A.vrc_NombreES 
    ,A.criterio 
    ,A.Periocidad 
    ,A.Fec_Ini_Period 
    ,A.OT 
    ,A.HM 
    ,A.SS 
    ,A.PA 

    from  tempdb..##Consolidado AS A
    where '+@WHERE+'
    Order BY A.tipo asc, A.int_AnoOT asc, A.Numero asc'


  PRINT( @SQL)
  EXEC( @SQL)
```

Comment: no tienes ningun mensaje de error?? aumenta la version de java y jasper

Comment: No sale ningún mensaje de error, si corro el sql profiler me sale la misma linea que sale con los reportes que funcionan bien y si pruebo esos datos directos al sp funciona bien. Al prinicipio me salia un msn en el jasper cuando intentaba cargar la tabla varia veces que decia que la tabla ya existía pero puse una condicional pal drop table y ya se soluciono. Ahora solo no carga nada se va en blanco

Comment: si quito la sentencia " exec dbo. sp_Crear_Tabla_Temp_Activos @CY ,@ID" el reporte "funciona" el problema es que esa sentencia es obligatoria para crear la tanla si no estaria trayendo los mismos datos, esto se da porque la funcion de jasper muere al primer exec entonces no toma el exec sql de abajo que es el que realmente manda los datos. Hay alguna manera de llamar un procedimiento de manera paralela cuando este sp se ejecute

Comment: Deberías etiquetar la base de datos, por cierto, PL/SQL en Oracle, T-SQL en SQL Server. ¿Utilizas pool de conexiones? considerando que las tablas temporales son por conexión.

Comment: Cuando hablo de plsql, es el lenguaje que uso para conectar los Sp con jasper y el pool de conexiones en el dataSource uso JDBC.

Comment: Detalla lo de la conexión que usa el Jasper, mejor aún, agrega a tu pregunta el código para llamar el reporte y el queryString del jrxml principal.

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Juan he aquí mi planteamiento.

- Las tablas temporales se crean en tempdb, y al crearlas se producen varios bloqueos sobre esta base de datos como por ejemplo
     en las tablas sysobjects y sysindex. Los bloqueos sobre tempdb
     afectan a todo el servidor.
- Al crearlas es necesario que se realicen accesos de escritura al disco ( no siempre si las tablas son pequeñas)
- Al introducir datos en las tablas temporales de nuevo se produce actividad en el disco, y ya sabemos que el acceso a disco
  suele ser
     el "cuello de botella" de nuestro sistema
- Al leer datos de la tabla temporal hay que recurrir de nuevo al disco. Además estos datos leídos de la tabla suelen combinarse con
     otros.
- Al borrar la tabla de nuevo hay que adquirir bloqueos sobre la base de datos tempdb y realizar operaciones en disco.
- Al usar tablas temporales dentro de un procedimiento almacenado perdemos la ventaja de tener compilado el plan de
  ejecución de dicho
     procedimiento almacenado y se producirán recompilaciones más a
     menudo. Lo mismo pasará cuando el server intenta reutilizar el plan
     de ejecución de una consulta parametrizada. Si en la consulta
     tenemos una tabla temporal difícilmente se reutilizará dicho plan de
     ejecución.

Vistos estos problemas mi consejo es.
En vez de tablas temporales podemos mejorar nuestro código para que no sean necesarias, si puedes **usa subconsultas o crea tabla física y ve truncando al final de su uso**.
**Saludos.**

Comment: Entiendo que lo ideal no es usar tablas temporales, por eso aclaro que toco, usar tablas físicas es mala idea podría estar sobrescribiendo hasta mas de mil registros, el caso es que no puedo usar variables tipo tabla porque el jasper no las lee y no puedo hacer la consulta en un solo query ya que esa tabla temporal viene de un llenado de tablas que no están relacionadas entre si en el modelo

Answer (score 0):

Si la preocupación es sobreescribir miles de registros, temo informar que ocurrirá lo mismo en una tabla temporal **global** (`##`) en un pool de conexiones.

Las tablas temporales se destruyen al cerrar la conexión, pero el trabajo de un pool es reutilizar conexiones. Al reutilizarse se invocará el procedimiento `sp_reset_connection` el cual -entre otras cosas- borrará tablas temporales **locales** (`#`).

Por lo anterior, y asumiendo que la conexión que le pasas al Jasper proviene del pool, deberías usar una *tabla temporal local*.

Comment: Al contrario la tabla temporal local no estaba cargando bien y por eso pasa a trabajar con tablas globales. Ya solucione el problema haciéndolo desde java con una función aja que me permite correr el sp de creación de la tabla temporal cuando ubican el cursor sobre el reporte, no era lo ideal pero por ahora ya que va estar creando la tala cada que se paren en el objeto, así no lo ejecuten pero bueno funciona :(

Comment: Por eso preguntaba por lo conexión y la invocación, si no funcionó con temporales locales me sugiere que hay algo mas, por ejemplo, si llamas mas de una vez a `getConnection()` hay que cuidar cuándo y dónde llamas a la creación de las tablas, cuidando la conexión que le pases al JasperFillManager. Por otro lado, si lo que te funciona es la tabla global sólo asegurate de probar con sesiones simultáneas.